# Tag suggestion: ImageJ

Tags: feature-request, tags

ImageJ can be a powerful tool for biologists in almost any fields. I've got a few imageJ questions that don't really fall under any particular tags we have going here like 'lab techniques' and I'm sure there are lots of questions that would fall under that tag from other members of the community.

Comment: Have you considered the ImageJ user's mailing list?

Answer (score 1):

I think this tag is too specific for now, I'd go with more general categories like image-processing for now. If we accumulate enough questions about ImageJ, creating a tag might make sense at some point.

Comment: I second this suggestion. If the task needs to be done using ImageJ/Fiji specifically, then I would suggest going to the ImageJ users mailing list.

Comment: I concur: I think this can be put under a general category of data/image analysis.